# Red color border flashes on clicking Send button

Tags: android, performance, android-strictmode

I'm making a chat application, where user types and when he hits enter button.
When I press Enter button, I'm getting red color flash around the entire screen and it disappears . How to handle this??

**NOTE:** Strict Mode is Disabled in Developer Options of Phone Settings.

[image]

Comment: Are you testing in emulator ?

Comment: Go to the `Device Settings` and find `Operation In Main Thread Notify Option`and Disable it

Comment: Turn off Developer options 'strict mode' and 'Show screen updates' mode. Then restart phone.

Comment: @GrIsHu no. Real device!

Comment: @Aksh already done. It didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same situation like yours.I did the following to get rid of it,

Go to `Setting/Developer options` then uncheck the protect SD card and Strict Mode option.

Comment: Have you read the question he has already disabled the strict mode option.

Comment: @GrIsHu: Yeah.In my case also, Strict Mode was disabled but again disabling SD card option solved it.I don't know how it works but it solved my problem.

Comment: @GrIsHu: I think as `Aksh` commented, restarting the phone will solve the problem.